# write html select with option in php code

Tags: php, html, oracle

I have in my html page this php code, how to user ...  from the echo.

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "select user_id, username,user_job from users");
    oci_execute($stid);

    while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid,OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))!= false){

        echo $row['user_id'] . " " . $row['username'] .$row['user_job'] . "<br>\n";
   }
```

Comment: unable to understand your question. Can you please elaborate

Comment: user_id, username, user_job, will be printed in line, with a space between each, how to put each of them using <select>option</select>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like below:

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "select user_id, username,user_job from users");
oci_execute($stid);

echo "<select>";
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid,OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))!= false){

    echo "<option value=$row[user_id]>". $row['username'] .$row['user_job'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: @don'tknownothing  glad to help you. BTW your name is interesting.

Comment: Don't forget to use upper case for the column names, e.g. `$row['USERNAME']` (unless the columns names were quoted when the table was created)